# execute oracle stored proc which accepts 2 input arg and return 2 out

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

execute oracle stored proc which accepts 2 input arg and return 2 out

```
variable arg1refcursor
variable arg2refcursor
variable arg3 refcursor
variable arg4 refcursor
exec  FOX_OWN.GET_FX_CUSIP('arg1', 'arg2', (sysdate+10), 'Y'), :arg1, :arg2, :arg3, :arg4)
print arg1
print arg2
print arg3
print arg4
```

???

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE         
GET_RESULT(
in_arg1 IN VARCHAR, 
in_arg2 IN VARCHAR, 
IN_arg3 IN DATE, 
out_arg1 OUT VARCHAR,
out_arg2 OUT VARCHAR,
out_arg3 OUT VARCHAR,
out_arg4 OUT NUMBER
)
as
.... 
...
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect `refcursor` to be returned, then you shouldn't use `VARCHAR2` (not `VARCHAR`!) as `OUT` datatype.

For example:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure get_result
  2    (par_deptno in emp.deptno%type,
  3     par_job    in emp.job%type,
  4     par_rc_emps out sys_refcursor,
  5     par_rc_jobs out sys_refcursor
  6    )
  7  is
  8  begin
  9    open par_rc_emps for
 10      select ename from emp
 11      where deptno = par_deptno;
 12
 13    open par_rc_jobs for
 14      select ename from emp
 15      where job = par_job;
 16  end;
 17  /

Procedure created.
```

Let's try it:

```
SQL> var v_rc_emps refcursor
SQL> var v_rc_jobs refcursor
SQL> exec get_result(20, 'CLERK', :v_rc_emps, :v_rc_jobs);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print v_rc_emps

ENAME
----------
SMITH
JONES
SCOTT
ADAMS
FORD

SQL> print v_rc_jobs

ENAME
----------
SMITH
JAMES
MILLER

SQL>
```